# How could I read an image in Python and rewrite it with a defined order of its pixels

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am currently trying to find a way to:

1. Read an Image-file using Python
2. Read all the Pixel Values as `HSV` Values
3. Order this Array of Values first by `H`, then by `S` and `V`
4. Make an image from this newly made Array with numpy.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would be very thankful.

Edit 1:

I have tried out some code and it does yield a result, but it's not the expected one. I guess, the np.sort does sort the tuples in total and not by one of the columns. Maybe someone's got an idea, how to solve this.

```
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import os
import colorsys

#definition of HSL/HSV colorspace
def hsl(x):
        to_float = lambda x : x / 255.0
        (r, g, b) = map(to_float, x)
        h, s, l = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r,g,b)
        h = h if 0 < h else 1 # 0 -> 1
        return h, s, l


#get the image filenames
images = glob.glob("test/*.jpg")
print(images)


#output_folder generation
output_folder = 'test/out_new'
if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)


#loop through all image filenames
for image in images:
    #load the current image
    im = Image.open(image) 
    
    #get a tuple of the x and y dimensions of the image
    width, height = im.size

    # creating empty img-array with same dimensions
    data = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    #load the pixel info of image
    pix = im.load()
    width, height = im.size # get original size for processing

    img_filename = os.path.splitext(image)[0]+'_sorted.jpg'
    img_filename = os.path.split(img_filename)[1]
    img_filename = os.path.join(output_folder, img_filename)

        
    dataset = {}

    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            h = (pix[x,y][0])
            s = (pix[x,y][1])
            l = (pix[x,y][2])
            #make a unique id for this color to use as key
            uid = f'{h},{s},{l}'
        

            # use h,s,l pixel output for image. switched axis due to bug in 
            data[y][x] = [h, s, l]
            # uncomment for r,g,b pixel output for image
            #data[y][x] = [r, g, b]

            if not uid in dataset:
                dataset[uid] = 0
            #count one up for this key
            dataset[uid] += 1

         

    # sort pixel 
    data_sorted = np.sort(data, axis=0)
    # create image
    newimage = Image.fromarray(data_sorted)
    #newimage = Image.fromarray(data)
    # save image
    newimage.save(img_filename)
```

Edit 2:
The Code Mark provided does sadly not yield the expected result.
The image that is created by the code should contain the same colored pixels as the original image did, but in a sorted manner. So every color of the original should still be visible.
*I am doing all this to to create a way of (quasi)visualizing the three dimensions of the H,S and V array in a two dimensional image.*

The original image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmiOE.jpg

The image produced by Marks code
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/foHGC.jpg

Thank you so much for the answers so far!

Marks code actually does kind of what it's supposed to do, if i commetn out the conversion to HSV. An Example is attached.

The sorted RGB Values
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWiY1.jpg

Comment: If you work with NumPy arrays, have you checked [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/)? See [`cv2.imread`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56), [`cv2.cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab), and [`cv2.imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce).

Comment: I actually haven't tried OpenCV yet. I will give it a shot. Thanks so far

Comment: as i understood it, the cv2.imread does not actually contain the pixel-information but rather a specific cv2-info. If i'm mistaken, what would be the benfit of using cv2 insteand of PIL to import the image?

Comment: cv2.imread will contain pixel-information about the image. [Furthermore you can convert color spaces by using cv2.cvtColor()](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html). Note that CV2 reads images as BGR instead of RGB

Comment: What would the purpose of this be please? Do you have a sample input and corresponding expected output image please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that hopefully does what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load image and convert to HSV
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('HSV')

# Convert to Numpy array and reshape to column vector of HSV pixels
pv = np.array(im).reshape(-1,3)

# Sort by H, S, V and convert back to original shape
res = pv[np.lexsort((pv[:,2], pv[:,1],pv[:,0]))]
res = res.reshape((im.height,im.width,3))

# Convert back to PIL Image, back to RGB and save
Image.fromarray(res, mode='HSV').convert('RGB').save('result.png')
```

Comment: Hey Mark, 
thank you so much for the code.

I am currentky working on a project about architectural visualization (the actual architectural images of buildings) and would like to try out ways to objectify the images. 

One way would be, to sort the Pixels of an image by their H,S and V Values to make this Information visually accessible.

Your Code though provides an image that is not of the expected outcome.
The Pixel Values do not seem to work out in the correct way. And since i haven't managed to get the code right, i can not provide a sample image. I will try to make an easy one!

Comment: You can maybe try changing the last line to `Image.fromarray(res, mode='HSV').convert('RGB').save('result.png')`

Comment: This obviously worked like a charm. I will start working on the code and the images. Thank you Mark!

Comment: Excellent - I'm glad it worked for you. Good luck with your project and, remember questions (and answers) are free, so come back if you get stuck again.

Comment: I have updated the code for future readers, with the correction.